# Prove with geometry: $\lfloor\frac{p}{q}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{2p}{q}\rfloor+\cdots+\lfloor\frac{(q-1)p}{q}\rfloor=(p-1)(q-1)/2$, for coprime $p$, $q$

Tags: geometry, ceiling-and-floor-functions, integer-lattices

> The question is to prove this using geometry: For $p$ and $q$ coprime,
>   $$\left\lfloor\frac{p}{q}\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor\frac{2p}{q}\right\rfloor+\cdots + \left\lfloor\frac{(q-1)p}{q}\right\rfloor = \frac12(p-1)(q-1)$$

I could think of nothing else but the fact that $\frac12(p-1)(q-1)$ is the number of points inside the triangle I drew (basically a rectangle with dimension $p,q$ and the triangle is formed by diagonal).

Can anyone give any small hints so that I proceed further or how can we relate the number of integral points inside the triangle with the diagonal? Would drawing lines further of which make the slope of $2p/q$ etc help?

Comment: According to you, $\frac{(p-1)(q-1)}2$ is an integer because... (?)

Comment: Either the identity is wrong or there are some conditions you're not telling us about. The left side depends on $r$ but the right side does not. I recommend to take several steps back and explain everything you know about where this identity comes from, what the symbols in it mean, and why you think it should be true.

Comment: P and q are coprime therefore both can't be odd . And q-1 was there very sorry for that

Answer (score 3):

I think you have already found the answer, or are very close to it.

You have the observation that there are $(p-1)(q-1)$ lattice points inside a rectangle of width $p$ and height $q$ with corners at the lattice points
$(0,0)$ and $(p,q).$
The diagonal of that rectangle between those two points has the equation $y = \frac pq x.$

The fact that $p$ and $q$ are coprime is important because it means that the diagonal does not pass through any other integer lattice points between $(0,0)$ and $(p,q).$
So the diagonal does not just separate the lattice points inside the rectangle into three groups (one below the diagonal, an equal number above, and some points on the diagonal); it separates them into just *two* disjoint subsets with the same number of points in each.

Now you just need to identify the points below the diagonal with the terms
$\left\lfloor \frac pq\right\rfloor,$
$\left\lfloor \frac {2p}q\right\rfloor,$
$\left\lfloor \frac {3p}q\right\rfloor,$ and so forth.

As a step toward that, notice that the diagonal passes through the points
$\left(1,\frac pq\right),$ $\left(2,\frac{2p}q\right),$ 
$\left(3,\frac{3p}q\right),$ $\left(4,\frac{4p}q\right),$ and so forth.
Again, because $p$ and $q$ are coprime, none of those points is a lattice point.
Try counting the number of lattice points below each of those points
and above the bottom edge of the rectangle.

Comment: How do I find the GIF . . I didn't get ur ans somehow. Can you please explain it a little bit more about what you mean in "finding the point "?Thank you so much

Comment: Also can anyone tell why I was downvoted ? So that I improve ?

Comment: I'm not sure I recall, but I think the downvotes were cast before you fixed the major errors in the question ($r$ used instead of $q,$ and neglecting to mention that $p$ and $q$ are coprime). Hopefully the score will not go down any more.

Comment: I found the ans thank you v much

Comment: Essentially GIF or floor function is the number of lattice points beneath it . So it's sum should give overall lattice points ? Is this it ?

Comment: In other words the sum of GIFs is just a way to count the points one column at a time, yes. I think that is the idea.